# Limits inferior of differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, limsup-and-liminf

I am asking myself if for every differentiable function $f\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for every $x>0$ in a neighborhood of zero, we have

$$\liminf_{x\to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=0?$$

Consider $\displaystyle\lim_{\delta\to 0+} \inf\Big\{\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}:x\in (0,\delta)\Big\}$.

As the function $f$ is continuous, the numerator goes to $0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(x)>0\ \forall x>0$, we have by the $\varepsilon,\delta$-criterion: $$\forall \varepsilon >0 \ \exists \delta>0 \text{ such that } \forall x \in [0,\delta) \text{ we have } |f(x)|=f(x)<\varepsilon.$$

Hence, the difference quotient $\frac{f(x)- f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}{x}>0 \ \forall x>0$. My thought is to use the following intuitive argument: If $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for every $x>0$, then $f'(x)>0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$.

Comment: @Alex why do you say that $g/g' \to 0$ as $g'$ vanishes on $x_n \to 0$ and is negative nearby so in particular for any negative $-c$ one can find $y_n \to 0$ st $g(y_n)/g'(y_n)=-c$

Comment: @Conrad, Somehow last night I convinced myself this wouldn't be a counterexample, but looking at it again, I think you are right. You mean there is a sequence $x_n$ of points to the right of, but very close to the local maxima of $g$, such that $(g/g')(x_n) < -1$, say? I believe it is true. (The false assumption $g/g'\to 0$ came from plugging the limit into an online calculator!)

Comment: note that if $g'(x_n)=0$ then since $g(x_n)>0$ for $x_n$ small enough then $g/g'(x_n) \to -\infty$ as $x \to x_n$ form the side of $x_n$ where $g'<0$ so there are values near $x_n$ for which $g/g'$ is as negative as you want - probably  one can prove with more care that all negative values are taken infinitely many times

Comment: @Conrad, thanks for the nudge in the right direction. I updated my comment into an answer to the OP's question

Comment: @Alex -a natural question is if the liminf here can be anything but zero or minus infinity and in particular if it can be strictly positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) + \frac{x}{10}, & x > 0 \\
0, & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
is a counterexample. You can check that $g(x)>0$ for all $x > 0$ sufficiently small, and that $g$ is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$.

First I will give a heuristic argument, and then I will sketch a more detailed one.
Indeed, choose a sequence $x_n\searrow 0$ such that $g'(x_n)>-x_n$ (say by looking  very closely to the right of a sequence of local maxima of $g$). For $n$ sufficiently large, $g(x_n) < x_n$ as the quadratic term becomes negligible, so for these points $x_n$,
$$
\frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)} <\frac{x_n}{-x_n} = -1.
$$
Hence $\liminf_{x\to 0^+}\frac{g(x)}{g'(x)} \le -1$.

Being a little bit more careful, I think it is possible to prove the following lemma. Let $\{y_n\}$ be the sequence of local maxima of $g$ in the interval $(0,\frac{1}{10})$, arranged so that $y_1 > y_2 > \dots$.

**Lemma.** There exists constants $C>c>0$ so that for each $n=1,2,\dots$, $-C < g''(y_n) < -c$.

The idea of the lemma is that near a local maximum of $g$, $g$ looks like an upside-down parabola with a fixed aspect ratio (the parabolas are not getting relatively skinnier or fatter as $x\to 0^+$).

Next, expand $g'(y_n+\epsilon_n) \approx g''(y_n)\epsilon_n \approx -\epsilon_n$, and set $x_n = y_n + \epsilon_n$. For $n$ very large, we still have $g(x_n) < x_n$ as the quadratic term becomes negligible, and we also have
$$
\frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)} \approx \frac{x_n}{-\epsilon_n}.
$$
Note the freedom we have to choose $\epsilon_n$ as small as we like, say $\epsilon_n < x_n^2$. This shows how we can prove for this function $g$, we have
$$
\liminf_{x\to 0^+}\frac{g(x)}{g'(x)} = -\infty
$$